# Does OnLoadConfig from custom Global.scala execute for tests run in Eclipse? (Play 2 / Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit, playframework-2.0

We have four `application.conf` files (`application.conf`, `application.dev.conf`, `application.test.conf`, and `application.prod.conf`).  All of the details are in the main `application.conf` file whereas the others only contains the `db.default` information (driver, url, user, and pass).  We are using Java on the Play 2 framework.

We have a Global.scala file which ensures the correct application.x.conf file is included in the normal application.conf file:

```
  override def onLoadConfig(config: Configuration, path: File, classLoader: ClassLoader, mode: Mode.Mode): Configuration = {
    /**
     * When the Play application is loaded, depending on which "mode" is set in application.conf (dev, test, or prod),
     * that specific configuration file is loaded by this overridden method.
     */
  val modeSpecificConfig = config ++ Configuration(ConfigFactory.load(s"application.${mode.toString.toLowerCase}.conf"))
  super.onLoadConfig(modeSpecificConfig, path, classLoader, mode)
  }
```

After starting play with `play run` in the command prompt, I would like to run the tests in JUnit in Eclipse, but am running into configuration errors.  Does the code in the Global.scala above run upon test execution (in Eclipse)?  If not, how can I get the tests to run properly in Eclipse?

---

Other information:

I have a BaseModelTest.java file which looks for the "default" settings from the application.conf file (which is extended by the other conf files):

@Before
  public void dropCreateDb() throws IOException {

```
String serverName = "default";

EbeanServer server = Ebean.getServer(serverName);
ServerConfig config = new ServerConfig();
DdlGenerator ddl = new DdlGenerator(); // (SpiEbeanServer) server, new MySqlPlatform(), config);
ddl.setup((SpiEbeanServer) server, new MySqlPlatform(), config);

// Drop
ddl.runScript(false, ddl.generateDropDdl());

// Create
ddl.runScript(false, ddl.generateCreateDdl());
```

}

---

The current configuration error that I am receiving is:

```
Configuration error: Configuration error[path parameter: Invalid path ' - could not find datasource for default': Token not allowed in path expression: '-' (Invalid number: '-') (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:92)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570)
    at play.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.java:307)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:47)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
    at play.api.Play.start(Play.scala)
    at play.test.Helpers.start(Helpers.java:359)
    at models.BaseModelTest.startApp(BaseModelTest.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path ' - could not find datasource for default': Token not allowed in path expression: '-' (Invalid number: '-') (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePathExpression(Parser.java:934)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePath(Parser.java:974)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.Path.newPath(Path.java:220)
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.hasPath(SimpleConfig.java:71)
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.play$api$db$BoneCPApi$$error(DB.scala:278)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$5.apply(DB.scala:426)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi$$anonfun$getDataSource$5.apply(DB.scala:426)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at play.api.db.BoneCPApi.getDataSource(DB.scala:426)
    at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$getDataSource$1.apply(DB.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DB$$anonfun$getDataSource$1.apply(DB.scala:142)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.db.DB$.getDataSource(DB.scala:142)
    at play.api.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.scala)
    at play.db.DB.getDataSource(DB.java:22)
    at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:45)
    ... 27 more
```